# AWS QuickSight CreateGroup operation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I was following this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/embedded-analytics-tutorial-introduction/module-six/)(Create and Execute Initial setup Lambda for Dashboard Embedding) to run lambda function for setup QuickSight user and groups.

My QuickSight region is `ap-southeast-1`, when I test the lambda function on aws console, I got this error:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateGroup operation: Operation is being called from endpoint ap-southeast-1, but your identity region is us-east-1. Please use the us-east-1 endpoint.",
  "errorType": "AccessDeniedException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/embedSetUp.py\", line 27, in handler\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/embedSetUp.py\", line 21, in handler\n    res = qs.create_group(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I also found out
`creatGroup` API on AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_CreateGroup.html), it says

> The permissions resource is `arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:<relevant-aws-account-id>:group/default/<group-name>`.

What is the correct way to use this CreateGroup API if my QuickSight account is in `ap-southeast-1`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found that I should set `dashboardRegion` and `identityRegion` to `us-east-1`, then it works!